# On a graph, is the integral of a function with respect to a measure conceptually equivalent to an integral with respect to another function?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Riemann integrals of the form $\int f(x)\,dx$ with respect to a single variable are pretty simple; they work like this:

[image: single variable]

Sometimes, integrals take the form $\int f(u(x))\,d(u(x))$ where $u$ is another function—but these aren’t too different either:

[image: another function]

To be explicit, one has the transformation $$\int f(u(x)\,d(u(x)) = \int f(u(x)) \, \frac{du}{dx} \, dx$$

Is this how integrals with respect to measures, of the form $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ or [the like](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5237/347062), are evaluated?

I have tried researching basic measure theory for many days, but it seems pretty convoluted when broaching the topic of integrals. Hopefully I will be getting a book on measure theory and integration soon. In the mean time, I would appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on how measures are involved in the computation of integrals.