# Notation used in integration in stochastic processes

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In studying stochastic processes, I have come across the Lebesgue integral applied to a probability space, i.e. $$\int_M f d\textbf{P}$$ But I have also come across the notation $$\int_M f \textbf{P}(d\omega)$$
It seems to me that these are the same, as I have consulted several textbooks which seem to use them at different times in slightly different contexts? Can someone shed some light on this, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/is-there-any-difference-between-the-notations-int-fxd-mux-and-int-fx?

Comment: @md5 yes I think it does thank you